# БД с иерархической классификацией и добавление фасетов, реализация?

Tags: php, mysql

Изучаю php, поставили задачу расширить иерархическую систему состоящую из 2 таблиц "категория" (`id`, `parent_id`, `name`) и "товары" (`code`, `name`), Связи в таблице "товары2категория" (`id`, `code`).

Необходимо расширить систему фасетной классификацией. Каждая группа товаров (из иерархического классификатора) характеризуются набором фасетов и единицами измерения этих фасетов. Может ли кто схематически нарисовать, как эти фасеты будут создаваться или объяснить?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы делал так

1) сами фасеты - это просто справочники, таблицы с id, название
2) фасетные данные о товарах - это таблицы для связи много ко многим, поля ид товара (code), id фасеты

Если фасеты могут иметь значение - не знаю бывает ли такое, просто на всякий случай, то таблица из 2) получает дополнительное поле - значение.

Comment: Спасибо, в принципе так и предполагал, что это будут как бы справочники.Не совсем конечно понял, что Вы имеете в виду за значения могут быть в этих фасетах, я так понимаю, например из таблицы товары: бумага копировальная, создаем фасет, где есть столбцы например: качество, кол-во листов, бренд, ед измерения(пачка). Необходимо создать механизм добавления, редактирования и удаления фасетов из группы. Товары должны иметь интерфейс для заполнения значений фасетов той группы, к которым они принадлежат. А как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: Получается для каждой группы товаров нужно сделать какой то шаблон, который будет создавать фасетную таблицу и давать возможность заносить определенные данные?